# How to install imagemagick on android?

Tags: python, android, imagemagick, pydroid

I am writing python code on android using Pydroid app. Able to install pip packages, but imagemagick, which is requirement for image generation, as I understand, is a binary. I have access to terminal emulator, but don't know command that would work on android. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Writing Python on Android is specialized and you should mention how you are doing it. You had mentioned PyDroid in a previous question, but you might be using [Termux](https://termux.dev/en/) (don't use the Google Play version - no longer supported).

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, I am using pydroid, what else would be useful to mention?

Comment: You should confirm that you installed the Pydroid repository plugin from the Play Store, what you tried, and mention which device make/model and OS version of Android you are using. Alternatively I would use Termux as it is (a) open-source and (b) easier to find support (reddit) and (c) [supports imagemagick](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/imagemagick) and [Python](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Image_Editors#Python).